# How to execute nvm from docker run

Tags: node.js, docker, nvm

I have a bare docker image with globally installed nvm and latest lts nodejs. Everything operates as expected except one thing. I am not able to execute nvm using docker run:

```
docker run -ti myimage:latest nvm
```

This produces output

```
--: line 0: exec: nvm: not found
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV NVM_DIR='/usr/local/nvm'
RUN mkdir -pv "$NVM_DIR" && \
    apt-get -yq clean && apt-get -q update && \
    apt-get -yq --no-install-recommends install curl ca-certificates git-core && \
    curl -o- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh' | bash && \
    . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && \
    nvm install --default --latest-npm 'lts/*' && \
    apt-get -yq clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", ". /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh && { [ \"x$*\" = 'x' ] || { exec ${@} ; exit $? ; } ; } && bash", "--"]
```

Comment: Would it be simpler to directly [install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) in the Dockerfile, without using a version manager?  Or to use the [Docker Hub `node` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node)?  (Version managers like `nvm` tend to introduce complexities like what you're running into, but an image will almost always have only a single language runtime in it.)

Comment: This is more search for explanation on why it behaves like this. I know docker with nodejs can be done in several different ways but this question is not about that.

Comment: @DavidMaze So in the OP's case where they're simply `FROM ubuntu:20.04` generically that's a reasonable thing to ask, however the situation can certainly come up — in my case I found this because I was trying to "roughly" containerize a mixed Python backend / node.js-compiled frontend app and didn't want to mess with splitting it into a whole `docker-compose` setup or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured this one out. The reason nvm does not execute is because it is not executable at all but preloaded bash function so it has to be executed directly and not through exec. This is what works:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV NVM_DIR='/usr/local/nvm'
RUN mkdir -pv "$NVM_DIR" && \
    apt-get -yq clean && apt-get -q update && \
    apt-get -yq --no-install-recommends install curl ca-certificates git-core && \
    curl -o- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh' | bash && \
    . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && \
    nvm install --default --latest-npm 'lts/*' && \
    apt-get -yq clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", ". /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh && { [ \"x$*\" = 'x' ] || { ${@} ; exit $? ; } ; } && bash", "--"]
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems ± reasonable but the `. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"` part exits with code `3` for me with the same `v0.39.3` — and since Docker's `RUN` isn't really a shell itself it's a bit of a puzzle how that `source`/`.` would supposed to be working there 

Comment: Ah, so contrary to some older answers about Docker here, it appears that command **does** get run in a shell because my errors themselves say e.g `/bin/sh: 1: source: not found` when I change the `.` to `source`. So I'm guessing this is a difference between my Debian-based `FROM python:3.8` (where /bin/sh links to dash) vs. your `FROM ubuntu:20.04` or something.

Comment: So my own issue turned out to be a combo of two things: I was trying to `. $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh` in a working directory that had an `.nvmrc` and it was quietly upset that I hadn't **already installed** the necessary version (see https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1985#issuecomment-456022013). So my initial source command needed to be `. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" --no-use` but to get that to work I had to first `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]` since Debian's dash shell didn't seem to be passing the `--no-use` bit. (Other option could have been to change workdir temporarily or something….)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the variant that worked for me in a Docker container which happened to be `FROM python:3.8` which is Debian-based:

```
WORKDIR $APP_ROOT
COPY .nvmrc package.json package-lock.json ./
# WORKAROUND: Debian's default `dash` shell doesn't play nice with the `--no-use` param below
# which is itself needed to avoid <https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1985#issuecomment-456022013>
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash && \
    . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" --no-use && nvm install && npm ci
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

Basically I didn't need to install quite as many miscellaneous system dependencies as in the other answer here, but I did have to deal with the interplay between two different problems:

- my working directory already had `.nvmrc` in it, but the nvm setup script exits with code 3 if that version of node isn't **already** installed.
- and for some reason Debian's default (very basic) `dash` shell didn't seem to be passing along the `--no-use` argument that was needed

I should mention, though, that I also have an explicit:

```
ENV NVM_DIR=/nvm
RUN mkdir -p "$NVM_DIR" && chown $APP_UID:$APP_GID "$NVM_DIR"
```

earlier in my script but I don't think that's particularly necessary; one could more typically just `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"` as part of the command after the default install i.e.

```
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash && \
    export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" && \
    . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" --no-use && \
    nvm install && npm ci
```

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to what I asked for here. I was trying to execute nvm from the already built custom docker image using docker run command.

Comment: @DarkoMiletic Ah! I see, so your question was more about the `ENTRYPOINT` and less about the initial `nvm install` — sorry for the noise then, I can delete my answer and/or find a better home for it if you prefer!